# Should I call SDL_ConvertSurface right before SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

Is there a significant benefit (or any benefit at all), when I convert SDL surface and create a texture from optimized surface?

Here is example of what I mean:

```
loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path);
optimSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(loadedSurface, SURFACE_FORMAT, 0);
loadedTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, optimSurface);
//return loadedTexture and destroy the rest

/*  VS  */

loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path);
loadedTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
//return loadedTexture and destroy the rest
```

According to SDL2 [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ConvertSurface)

> This function is used to optimize images for faster repeat blitting. This is accomplished by converting the original and storing the result as a new surface. The new, optimized surface can then be used as the source for future blits, making them faster.

Its tied with surface blitting, but I can't say its effect "within" texture.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the source for SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface. [It calls SDL_ConvertSurface already](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/31dde825735a242c85a8feeed3129c05b75ae751/src/render/SDL_render.c#L691). So using SDL_ConvertSurface is entirely redundant.

I took a quick peek at what `SDL_ConvertSurface` does in the SDL source code ([GitHub mirror here](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/src/video/SDL_surface.c#L939)), and it seems to just change surface internals, if even that.

The only way I could imagine that had an effect would be to save on the conversion/data transmit that is performed when the texture data is sent onto the GPU, but I highly doubt that actually makes a difference here. So I would not call `SDL_ConvertSurface`.

In general, with SDL2, you can discard most of the surface manipulation, since the focus is in the hardware accelerated renderer.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you for pointing me to the sources. It's much easier to see than I thought.